# Move a 2d point to a target point with certain speed through x or y axis

Tags: point

Given that moving a point A(x1,y1) to location (x2,y2) with a fixed speed, say 3 units(points) per sec.

The requirement is that the point A can only moves through x or y axis.

For example, A(0,0) moves to target(10,10) at 3units/sec. First starting move on x axis, after 1s, location of A becomes (3,0). Then becomes (9,0) after 3s. Now on the x axis, the A only needs to move 1 more unit and then move 2 units on the y axis, which becomes (10,2), then continue on the y axis, (10,5)...(10,8)

My question is: Is there any efficient way to achieve this? This is my logic:

```
while(the point is not arriving the target point) {
 currentX = SourceX;
 currentY = SourceY;
 differenceOnXaxis=TargetX-currentX;
 differenceOnYaxis=TargetY-currentY;

 if(differenceOnXaxis == 0) {
   if(differenceOnYaxis == 0) {
     //Arrive at the target point
   } else if (differenceOnYaxis >= MovingUnit){
     currentY +=  MovingUnit;
   } else if (0 <differenceOnYaxis < MovingUnit){
     currentY +=  differenceOnYaxis;
   } else if (-MovingUnit <differenceOnYaxis < 0) {
     currentY += differenceOnYaxis;
   } else if (differenceOnYaxis<= (-MovingUnit)) {
     currentY -= MovingUnit;
   }
 } else if(differenceOnXaxis >= MovingUnit){
   currentX += moving unit;
 } else if (0< differenceOnXaxis < MovingUnit) {
   currentX += differenceOnXaxis;
   if(differenceOnYaxis > 0){
    currentY += (MovingUnit - differenceOnXaxis)
   } else if (differenceOnYaxis < 0) {
    currentY += -(MovingUnit-differenceOnXaxis)
   }
 } else if (- MovingUnit < differenceOnXaxis < 0) {
   currentX += differenceOnXaxis;
 } else if (differenceOnXaxis <= (-MovingUnit)) {
   currentX -= MovingUnit;
 } 
}
```